# Oarcle Connection cache property - What is significance of TimeToLiveTimeout

Tags: oracle, database-connection

From [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/concache.htm)

> Sets the maximum time in seconds that a logical connection can remain open. When TimeToLiveTimeout expires, the logical connection is unconditionally closed, the relevant statement handles are canceled, and the underlying physical connection is returned to the cache for reuse.

How to see it working in real scenario for specific time set to TimeToLiveTimeout?

What are valid values we can set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a use case for timetolivetimeout at the bottom of your link.
Basically, if your session is stateless, the it OK to turn timeout on.

Also, more information could be obtained here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/core.1013/b28942/top_issues.htm

0 is a valid value (no timeout)

60 is OK for some applications

120 is OK for some others

and so on.

Monitor your system and adjust.